# How to change xaxis location in flotcharts?

Tags: javascript, html, css, charts, jfreechart

Consider the options :

```
<style type="text/css">
    .wrapperClass .xAxis .tickLabel{margin-left:40px;}
</style>

var options = {                      
    series: {
        lines: {
            show: true,
            color: "#CCFFCC"
        },
        points: { show: true }
    },
    xaxis: {
        show: true,
        mode: "time",                                          
        font :{
            color: "Green",
            size: 16
        }
    },
    yaxis: {
        show: true,
        tickDecimals: 0
        minTickSize : 1, 
    }
}
```

And :

```
<div class="wrapperClass">
    var plotChart = $('.someChart').plot(myJson, options).data("plot");
</div>
```

How can I move the `xaxis` left by `40px` ?

I searched in the documentation [here](https://flot.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/API.txt) but didn't find a clear way .

Any thoughts ?

Much appreciated

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle of what you currently have?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding this:

```
.xAxis .tickLabel{margin-left:40px;}
```

to your CSS. Let me know if this is what you want.

Comment: How can I add that code inside the options ? In the CSS it doesn't work

Comment: How does that not work?@ron Look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/b8p0nr7L/2/

Comment: I edited the code above . I tried to attach the `div` with the CSS code , but it doesn't work .

Comment: first off all, I do not understand how you can do: `<div class="wrapperClass">
    var plotChart = $('.someChart').plot(myJson, options).data("plot");
</div>` you can not have javascript code inside a div @ron, second it works but i do not know why it does not work in your case